# Pythonic way to set module-wide settings from external file

Tags: python, config, configuration-files

**Some background (not mandatory, but might be nice to know):** I am writing a Python command-line module which is a wrapper around `latexdiff`. It basically replaces all `\cite{ref1, ref2, ...}` commands in LaTeX files with written-out and properly formatted references before passing the files to `latexdiff`, so that `latexdiff` will properly mark changes to references in the text (otherwise, it treats the whole `\cite{...}` command as a single "word"). All the code is currently in a single file which can be run with `python -m latexdiff-cite`, and I have not yet decided how to package or distribute it. To make the script useful for anybody else, the citation formatting needs to be configurable. I have implemented an optional command-line argument `-c CONFIGFILE` to allow the user to point to their own JSON config file (a default file resides in the module folder and is loaded if the argument is not used).

**Current implementation:** My single-file command-line Python module currently parses command-line arguments in `if __name__ == '__main__'`, and loads the config file (specified by the user in `-c CONFIGFILE`) here before running the main function of the program. The config variable is thus available in the entire module and all is well. However, I'm considering publishing to PyPI by following [this guide](https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/) which seems to require me to put the command-line parsing in a `main()` function, which means the config variable will *not* be available to the other functions unless passed down as arguments to where it's needed. This "passing down by arguments" method seems a little cluttered to me.

**Question:** Is there a more pythonic way to set some configuration globals in a module or otherwise accomplish what I'm trying to? (I don't want to rely on 3rd party modules.) Am I perhaps completely off the tracks in some fundamental way?

Comment: Usually one passes the configuration to the class constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use classes for this project, but in other projects I have done just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is to have the configurations defined in a class or a simple dict:

```
class Config(object):
    setting1 = "default_value"
    setting2 = "default_value"

    @staticmethod
    def load_config(json_file):
        """ load settings from config file """
        with open(json_file) as f:
            config = json.load(f)
        for k, v in config.iteritems():
            setattr(Config, k, v)
```

Then your application can access the settings via this class: `Config.setting1` ...

Comment: Wow! I had no idea that was possible. Solves my problem in a neat way. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder though, is it good practice to use and manipulate classes directly like this without instantiating them, or is this a case of "there's a better way to structure your program"?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be "good practice"? It fits your requirement which is a single access point for configurations, sounds just about right to me (without the need for complicating things). This is inspired from how configurations are done with Flask.